# complexe regex to capture a value

Tags: regex

I am trying to capture a value from a web source page.
The source page is like this :

```
                    <span class="old-price">
            <!--<span class="price-label"></span>-->
            <span class="price" id="old-price-10779">
                44,95 €                </span>
        </span>
```

I want to capture the price. So this is my regex :

```
price" id="old-price-10779">\r*\n*                    (.*?) €
```

Everything is working well, the value is well captured. The only problem is that my regex is depending of the "10779" value, but this value can change, so I was wondering how to indicate to my regex that this value can be any number and not only this fix value : 10779.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Please add the regex flavor as a tag. Different languages have different implementations of regular expressions.

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Answer (score 1):

```
price" id="old-price-\d+">\s*(.*?) €
```

This should do it for you.See demo.

https://www.regex101.com/r/rK5lU1/29

Just replace the number by `\d+`

Comment: Your just regex is just fine. I think he has a problem with the regex's language implementation.

Comment: May I suggest the following improvement to the solution:
price['"] id=['"]old-price-\d+['"]>\s*([\d,.]+)\s€

Explaining: sometimes, you won't have the double quote, but instead, the simple quote. Plus, the group could be better identified with digits+comma+dot.  

It works fine if you test it [here](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: @vianna77 nice improvement ...thanx :)